# GRUB Error after installing Ubuntu 14.04 erasing everything of 16.04

Tags: boot, grub2, 16.04

I had Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my system. Today i tried to install 14.04 erasing everything of 16.04. But now i am getting GRUB Error. Something like "minimal BASH-like line editing" . .. Can someone give me a good solution .

Comment: Seems like it can't find the Ubuntu partition. Did you make sure to completely wipe the disk of the Ubuntu 16.04 installation?

Comment: I am not sure about it really. If i didn't then what do i have to do now ?

Comment: Reinstall. Delete all partitions and format the drive as Ext4, then boot a USB and install 16.04.